# A term to describe the phenomenon that people travel more and know much better abroad but interestingly, than their local country/city?

Tags: single-word-requests

I don't know if you have noticed that a lot of people who like travelling abroad have actually not been to many places in their own city, probably because it's so close to their home that they think they can visit at any time, hence they keep deferring ... and the result is that they have never visited a lot of local attractions even once in their life. *You* might even qualify!

For example, a Parisian might have been to many great tourist attraction sites around the world, like the Great Wall, the Iguaçu Falls, Machu Picchu, Angkor Wat, but have never visited le Musée du Louvre, despite it being located within his/her city.

I have encountered this many many times in my life (including myself; I haven't been to the Great Bronze Buddha or Disneyland in Hong Kong after living there for many years). I'd like to know if there is a single word to describe this phenomenon.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Disneyland? You must be joking.

Comment: 'Drawing in one's horns' applies, but is a gross hypernym.

Comment: It's so common and so widely remarked on, there must be some term for it. There is also a lot of writing in the tourism industry, people doing academic work on tourism management, museum studies, event management, etc, and they must refer to it.

Comment: [Cultural tourism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cultural_tourism) is related. There is probably no exact term as it is just a general mindset of locals that local attractions are "right at your doorstep" and locals delay visiting these places thinking they can get to it sooner or later.

Answer (score 1):

You can describe the person you are referring to as ***[xenophile:](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/xenophile)***

> : one attracted to foreign things (such as styles or people)

(M-W)

Comment: Thank you for your answer, however, although xenophile covers the part where a person is attracted to foreign things, it misses out on the part where the local person didn't visit his/her own city/country because he/she thinks "it's too easily available"......

Comment: @ProudHKer - xenophiles, being more attracted by foreign cultures, arts and life styles would automatically tend to spend their time traveling abroad  or find information about foreign things rather than caring about what’s around them at home. Xenophiles are, for some reason, prejudiced against their own culture.

Comment: I am not at all sure that being a xenophile suggests you are an _oikoiophobe_ (or whatever the word for being prejudiced against your own), it only means that you like the other. That doesn't imply *dis*liking your own culture, it only implies you (also?) like others'.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is a single word, though this is (in my experience) a common situation. You might be able to force ***anti-nationalist*** into service here, though it's admittedly not the same concept.

> opposed to nationalism or to a nationalist movement or government

[MW](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/anti-nationalist)

Nationalism is defined as

> placing primary emphasis on promotion of its culture and interests as opposed to those of other nations

[MW](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/nationalism)

This really has nothing to do with seeing the local sights.